# argument between 2 date mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arguments

I have a Mysql problem. 
For example I have this kind of database:

Table : date_check

```
NAME | DATE_TIME

Luis | 14/10/2014 13:37:00
Charlie | 12/10/2014 12:25:00
```

Table : schedule

```
NAME | DATE_START | DATE_END

Luis | 02/10/2014 | 11/10/2014
Charlie | 08/10/2014 | 17/10/2014
```

==========================

then i want the result just like this :

```
NAME | DATE_TIME | result

Luis | 14/10/2014 13:37:00 | 0
Charlie | 12/10/2014 12:25:00 | 1
```

which Luis not get schedule in date_time 14/10/2014 13:37:00 (base on table schedule)

Thank you for your great help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This requires date arithmetic -- assuming the date and time columns are all using native format `dates` (and are not stored as character strings):

```
select s.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from schedule s
                where s.name = dc.name and
                      dc.date_time >= s.date_start and
                      dc.date_time < s.date_end + interval 1 day
               )
       ) as result
from date_check dc;
```

This assumes that the end date is "inclusive" -- meaning that all times on that day are included.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  a.NAME, 
  a.DATE_TIME, 
  if((select count(*) from schedule b 
                      where a.DATE_TIME>=b.DateStart 
                        and a.DATE_TIME>=b.DateEND 
                       and a.Name= b.Name)>0,1,0
    ) as result 
from date_check a
```